# CSS prevents links from acting like links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, effects

I'm just getting started on HTML5 and CSS3 (working through The Odin Project) and the first project is to duplicate the Google homepage. I was able to get everything set up, but it seems like my CSS is somehow preventing my header links from acting like links. You can't click on them and the hover effects don't work.

They work fine on my footer and my nav text-decoration is applied, so I'm not sure what's making it act like it's not a link. I've only tested it in Chrome, so I'm not even worried about compatability issues yet. Am I doing the HTML5 wrong? Or is it some kind of weird rule like you can't use hover effects with inline-block or something? I'm not familiar enough with it yet to have learned all those nuances yet...

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Google</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="atext">+Mara</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="atext">Gmail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="atext">Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="aicon"><img src="images/options.png" width="35px"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="aicon"><img src="images/bell.png" width="35px"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="aicon"><img src="images/plus.png" width="35px"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/photo.jpg" width="40px" class="rounded_img"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<img class="logo" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="320px"/>

<center><form action="#" method="post" name="google_search_form">
    <input type="search" name="googlesearch" class="search"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" class="button">
    <input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" class="button">
</form></center>
</div> <!--End container-->
<footer>
    <ul>
    <span class="left"><li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li></span>
    <span class="left"><li><a href="#">Business</a></li></span>
    <span class="left"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></span>
    <span class="right"><li><a href="#">Settings</a></li></span>
    <span class="right"><li><a href="#">Terms</a></li></span>
    <span class="right"><li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li></span>
    </ul>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 270px;
    clear: right;
}
.search {
    width: 650px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 27px;
    background: url('images/voice.gif') 97% 50% no-repeat;
    opacity:0.6;
    background-size: 17px;
    border: blue solid 1px;

}
.button {
    font-family: Helvetica, Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: #d6d6d6 solid 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 40px;
}
nav {
    width: 600px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Helvetica, Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
nav ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.atext {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.atext: hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.aicon {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.aicon:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
footer {
    width: 102%;
    height: 40px;
    left: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: #d6d6d6 solid 1px;
}
footer ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
footer li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
footer li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.rounded_img {
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Oh, and I haven't even started on JavaScript yet, so I'd like to avoid JavaScript if possible!

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvfmwhvu/

Comment: You probably have an element overlaying your links. Look for a large negative margin. Your browser's inspector would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your container element, if you remove the position relative it will work, but not sure if it will be maintained in the same position, but you can check it and modify your css accordingly:

```
.container{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you! Something so simple, how do you know which layer takes precedence? Is there anything I could read that might clear that up or is it something you just have to experiment with and get used to?

Comment: I recommend that you use the developers tools, in chrome you open it with f12 or ctrl+shift+i. Then you can use the inspect tool in order to see how the element is displayed. Using that tool, when I hovered in one of your links, instead of highlighting the anchor element, it highlighted the container div. With that I knew that the container was on top of the links, and then is a matter of tweaking and enabling/disabling css properties until you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Your main container isn't clearing the floated navbar. Because it falls later in your document, it has a higher layer index and covers the navbar. Try this:

```
.container {
    ...
    clear: both;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/drtcppoL/)**